# How to extract hidden li text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape from this [website](https://hypebeast.com/brands/jordan-brand), jump to each `href` article and scrape the comments located right after the main body text. However, I am getting blank results. Ive also tried fetching all `li` by writing `soup.find_all('li')` to check if any comments exist and found out that even extracting all li did not contain any comments about the article. Can anyone advice please? Im suspecting the website is making it harder to get the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://hypebeast.com/brands/jordan-brand'
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
        driver.get(url)
        products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='post-box    ']")))]
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        element = soup.select('.post-box    ')
        time.sleep(1)
        ahref = [item.find('a')['href']  for item in element]
        results = list(zip(ahref))
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)
        for result in results:
            res = driver.get(result[0])
            soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            time.sleep(6)
            comments_href = soup.find_all('ul', {'id': 'post-list'})
            print(comments_href)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post/comments are in an `<iframe>` tag. The tag also has a dynamic attribute that starts with `dsq-app`. So what you'll need to do is locate that iframe, switch to it, then you can parse. I choose to use BeautifulSoup to pull out the `script` tag, read that in as a json format and navigate through there. This should hopfully get you going with pull what you're looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
import json

urls = [
    'https://hypebeast.com/brands/jordan-brand'
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url)
        products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='post-box    ']")))]
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        element = soup.select('.post-box    ')
        time.sleep(1)
        ahref = [item.find('a')['href']  for item in element]
        results = list(zip(ahref))
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)
        for result in ahref:

            driver.get(result)
            time.sleep(6)

            iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@name, "dsq-app")]')

            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
            soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

            scripts = soup.find_all('script')
            for script in scripts:
                if 'response' in script.text:
                    jsonStr = script.text
                    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

                    for each in jsonData['response']['posts']:
                        author = each['author']['username']
                        message = each['raw_message']
                        print('%s: %s' %(author, message))
```

**Output:**

```
annvee: Lemme get them BDSM jordans fam
deathb4designer: Lmao
zenmasterchen: not sure why this model needed to exist in the first place
Spawnn: Issa flop.
disqus_lEPADa2ZPn: looks like an AF1
Lekkerdan: Hoodrat shoes.
rubnalntapia: Damn this are sweet
marcellusbarnes: Dope, and I hate Jordan lows
marcellusbarnes: The little jumpman on the back is dumb
chickenboihotsauce: copping those CPFM gonna be aids
lowercasegod: L's inbound
monalisadiamante: Sold out in 4 minutes. 
nickpurita: Those CPFM’s r overhyped AF.
...
```

Comment: hi Chitown88 - could you possibly also show a solution to merge all comments per ahref? Im dumping them in pandas dataframe exporting to csv and I want 1 cell to contain all comments.

Comment: yes that's easily done. So you want 1 cell that contains all the comments per href. couple questions: 1) do you want the username who made the comment included? How do you want the comments seperated (with a `;`)?. You just want 1 coulmn, with n number of rows?

Comment: 1) Yes I would like the username 2) separated with commas. And two columns, 1st being the href info and the 2nd being the username + comments. Thank you so much